# Error when new realm field added in android

Tags: android, deployment, realm

Whenever I add a new field in Realm class, it asks me to uninstall existing application and then run it. In this way all my existing application data is lost. My worry is, when I deploy my application to client and they start using it. So what if any changes occur which result in adding/removing any realm field. Will I need to uninstall existing application or is there any way to update existing application?

Answer (score 2):

You need to provide Migrations for Realm when changing the underlying data model. Have a look at the documentation: https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#migrations

If you want to get along without providing Migrations, make sure your data model fits your needs before you deploy your app.